# Get Google Calender to show guest names next to event

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-sites

I have a Google Site with an embedded Google Form.  This form is a registration form for daily events, with a very limited number of available slots.  Also on the site is the Google Calendar that lists these daily events.  When a person registers through the form, they are automatically added to the guest list on the calendar.  I would like to be able to have a list of those registered appear on the calendar, most likely in the Agenda view, next to the event for which they have registered.  How would I go about doing this?  I am not afraid of writing my own script if that is what it comes to, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: This would involve creating your own custom agenda view as a web app. Are you trying to manipulate GCal's own agenda view instead?

Comment: @BryanP Yes I am, and that is what I was afraid of

Comment: Another option would be to add the guests names to the event title so they are immediately visible. Such a script would be quite simple to write.